# Someone knows a strategy to bypass a html late load problem?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

Someone knows a strategy to bypass a html late load problem?

Here a table don't load the  on my page python request.

[image: response of my python request]
[image: contents after full loading on browser]

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: It seems like you will need to check javascript because it is javascript that is loading data in to the table. My recommendation is to find that URL where the data is being loaded from and then scrape that instead. Using chrome you can easily spot that with the network console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the API call for it. The root URL is: `https://br.advfn.com/common/bov-options/api`, and an example call is to `https://br.advfn.com/common/bov-options/api?symbol=PETR4`, where `PETR4` is passed as an argument.

Just use a GET request:

```py
import requests

symbol = "PETR4"
res = requests.get(f"https://br.advfn.com/common/bov-options/api?symbol={symbol}")

print(res)
```

The result:

```
{"result":[{"symbol":"PETRF286","type":"Call","style":"A","strike_price":"28,46","expiry_date":"18\/06\/2021","volume":"28912100","volume_form":"28.912.100","change_percentage":"25,0%","url":"\/p.php?pid=quote&symbol=BOV%5EPETRF286","class":"up"},{"symbol":"PETRF296","type":"Call","style":"A","strike_price":"28,96","expiry_date":"18\/06\/2021","volume":"25247000","volume_form":"25.247.000
...
```